# UDF works on some tables PySpark

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this UDF (the function body is irrelevant):

```
@F.udf(returnType=BooleanType())
def udf_foo(a, b):
     if not a or not b:
         return None
     return True
```

And this is how I filter my dfs:

```
df.filter(udf_foo(F.lit("bar"), F.col("baz"))).display()
```

However, it does run on my simple test DF, but when running it on a bigger (external) DF it will give me the error:

`Cannot evaluate expression: udf_foo(value, value)`

Does anyone recognize this error and know how to fix it?